# Find specific paragraph in web-page

Tags: html, css

I want to reach a specific paragraph in my web page - is this right?

CSS

```
div ul li p { /*is this right? */
    color:red;
    font-family:Arial;
}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><p>Grab me!</p></li>
            <li><p>Me, too!</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <p>Don't grab me!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I see some codes reaching...

```
<p>Grab me!</p>
<p>Me, too!</p>
```

Without adding `div ul` as selector, like this:

```
li p { /* someone do like this */
    color:red;
    font-family:Arial;
}
```

Comment: can you please describe little bit more?

Comment: i think above css code is correct but there are no Semicolons (;) after properties

Comment: it works if you place semicolons [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c83ebg85/)

Comment: lol @Our Man In Bananas,  you changed the code and put semi colon which was the issue of that question..:p

Comment: @Leothelion: I don't think I did, must have been a previous edit

Comment: lol @Leothelion No, it's me who did that

Comment: heheh..@jubiluk then what is the issue? please share with us..

Comment: ok sorry @Our Man In Bananas

Comment: @Leothelion you still don't get what's my question? pls. refresh ... I change things ....

Comment: i think i got your point..please check my solution or if i'm wrong then let me know..thanx

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to change the css with li and p tag only then use this,

```
li > p {
color:red;
font-family:Arial;
}
```

Hope it helps or let me know so i can help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

It is all about how your HTML was. Better approach is apply some unique `id` for the `div`. Refer the `div with id` then refer the child level div. Look at the following example.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><p>Grab me!</p></li>
        <li><p>Me, too!</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>Don't grab me!</p>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><p>One more Grab me!</p></li>
        <li><p>One more Me, too!</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>One more Don't grab me!</p>
```

In this case your code will select another section also. So that you have to add `id` for any one of the div, and refer it then reach it. I hope you know id should be unique. Just modify your code like below.

```
<div id="first-level">
    <ul>
        <li><p>Grab me!</p></li>
        <li><p>Me, too!</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>Don't grab me!</p>
<div id="second-level">
    <ul>
        <li><p>One more Grab me!</p></li>
        <li><p>One more Me, too!</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>One more Don't grab me!</p>
```

Apply your CSS like below.

```
div#first-level ul li p {
   color:red;
   font-family:Arial;
}

div#second-level ul li p {
   color:blue;
   font-family:Arial;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wpkg2g3k/)

Comment: sorry but he don't want to add more lines that's why he said use only li and p..see my answer which is more simple..but thanx for your ans too..

Comment: @Leothelion your answer will fail in my HTML structure

Comment: ohh then i will love to see that structure..please show me..thanx

Comment: it should not apply both the places.

Comment: @ Suresh..thanx for informing this..yes it can be problem but i just went through the op's line so..i will try to provide new solution and yup will use id too.. :)